optimize indexing while inside of a loop
i want to try optimizing this line of code:
for i in 0..len {
    slots[values[i].slot].count += 1;
}

(both of these lists are extremely long and the same size)
i have already optimized it like this(2.5x faster), to acess it in cache:
const PREFETCH_DISTANCE: usize = 32;
for i in (0..len).rev() {
    if i >= PREFETCH_DISTANCE {
        let pfs = values[i - PREFETCH_DISTANCE].slot;
        let fetch = &slots[pfs] as *const Slot as *const i8;
        unsafe { _mm_prefetch(fetch, _MM_HINT_T0) }
    }
    slots[values[i].slot].count += 1;
}

however it is still not as fast, as i was expecting. for example, this code, for the same list length is more than twice as fast, just because it doesn't index anything:
for val in &*arr {
    let ptr = val as *const T;
    let val = unsafe { ptr.read() };
    let dif = integrated_expected_distribution(&val) - start_val;
    debug_assert!(dif >= 0.);
    let slot = (dif * end_mult) as usize;
    debug_assert!(slot < len);
    values.push(Slottable { value: val, slot });
}

Am i missing something else, that i need to preload for that indexing? Or am i missing something, that causes performance issues?
here is a reproducable example:
    let amount = 100_000_000;
    let highest_possible_num = 1_000_000_000;
    let seed = 44;

    let mut rng = rand::rngs::StdRng::seed_from_u64(seed);

    let mut vec2: Vec<usize> = (0..amount)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..=highest_possible_num))
        .collect();
    let vec1: Vec<usize> = (0..amount).map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..amount)).collect();
    let len = amount;
    const PREFETCH_DISTANCE: usize = 32;
    let loop_ = Instant::now();
    for i in (0..len).rev() {
        if i >= PREFETCH_DISTANCE {
            let pfs = vec1[i - PREFETCH_DISTANCE];
            let fetch = &vec2[pfs] as *const usize as *const i8;
            unsafe { _mm_prefetch(fetch, _MM_HINT_T0) }
        }
        vec2[vec1[i]] += 1;
    }
    let loop_duration = loop_.elapsed();
    println!("Loop time: {:?}", loop_duration);

the removed count and slot are each just part of a datastructure of 8 byte, so the change shouldn't have any effect on the example
Edit: i think instruction-level parallelism can't be done on the loop, so it becomes slower.
Edit2: i've tested some more and Edit1 was wrong.
This code is waaay faster than my prefetched code:
    let mut test = 0;
    for i in (0..len).rev() {
        test += values[i].slot;
    }
    println!("test: {}", test);


Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. For example, does LLVM knows the lengths are equal and are len?

Also, are there any patterns in your data?

Also, what architectures do you need to support? Only x86-64? What target features?

it is supposed to be generalised, so no target features or patterns. it only needs to support x86-64. the lengths of all lists in my examples will always be equal, i don't know, what you mean by "does the LLVM know"

If you replace the indexing with get_unchecked(), does this help?

it had no noticeable effect. it was still around 205ms.

As I said, please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. We cannot proceed without that.

i edited it, to now include a reproducable example

Prefetching does not improve it 2x for me, only marginally (but it does improve). I tried to unroll the loop but no avail. Perhaps with scatter and gather instructions you can do better, but that requires AVX-512.

if prefetching does not improve it, either your compiler does so already or you need to increase prefetch distance to 64 or 128. scatter would indeed make it way better. sadly i dont have AVX-512.

Or my CPU does not need this prefetching... What is your CPU?

Intel Core i5-8250U. that doesn't seem right

Does prefetch not help only with your MRE, or also with your actual code?

Changing prefetch distance makes it (slightly) worse, 32 is the best value. Overall prefetching gives a ~60ms advantage on my machine (I doubled the number of items 10x, total time ~750ms with prefetching).

It definitely improves by 2.5x for me. The new count of 100_000_000 goes from 5.6s to 2.1s. While prefetching seems to be taking up most of the time it's still better to do it earlier. Also i found, that replacing _MM_HINT_T0 to _MM_HINT_NTA gives a slight improvement

So it does seem to be related to the CPU, I'm running laptop i9-13900HX, a bit more powerful than yours ;P

ooohh, then it might be, that your cpu already has better prefetching, so it doesn't need the prefetch instruction, to guide it. If i am right about that, then your cpu should be able to execute this in about 50ms for 100_000_000 elements (mine does in 150ms):
        let mut test = 0;
 for val in vec1 {
  test += val;
 }
 println!("test: {}", test);

